# How get data with jQuery.parseJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In page 1 I have this array:

```
$pole = array("countLike" => "countLike", "Message" => "Some message");
echo json_encode($pole);
```

And I want get this data on page 2, but this code doesn't work.

```
function Like(id)
{
    $.post("page1.php", { action: "Like", "id": id }, function(data) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $(".countLike#"+id).html(obj.countLike);
        $(".Message#"+id).html(obj.Message);
    });
}
```

Can you help me please with this code.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide your html code too?

Comment: Does `obj` actually contain what you want?  Inspect this with your browser's JavaScript debugging tools and find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `json` as expected output from the post request.

```
function Like(id)
{
    $.post("page1.php", { action: "Like", "id": id }, function(data) {

        //data is already a json parsed string

        $(".countLike#"+id).html(data.countLike);
        $(".Message#"+id).html(data.Message);
    }, "json"); // <<<<< This is what you missed
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks all of you for help. Special thanks to Starx, your answer was the best.

Answer (score 0):

Code should work making the request but there is an issue with your element selectors.

```
".countLike#"+id 
".Message#"+id
```

The "#" is not space separated from the class name. Issue now becomes are you looking for elements with ID "#"+id? I suspect you are so you really don't need the class prefixing the ID at all and simply use

```
$('#' + id)
```

An Id selector is far faster for jQuery to search than class since there can only be one in the page.